# Trying to reproduce a 3D picture in R of a Rate or a Proportion with plot3D

Tags: r, outer-join, plot3d, graphics3d

I saw this 3D picture the other day in a journal
that describes the evolution over time of Birth Rates between 1980-1999 by age. The vertical line is the birth rates. The two horizontal lines are, age, and year.

[image]

I really would like to reproduce one like this.
I can imagine the data would look something like (simplified)

```
dta = cbind(c(2000, 2005, 2015), 
  c(15, 20, 25), 
  c(20, 24, 35))

colnames(dta) <- c('year', 'age', 'rate')

 year age rate
 2000  15   20
 2005  20   24
 2015  25   35
```

I searched for some 3D libraries and package `plot3D` came out. I tried to figure out how the function `outer()` works but I couldn't understand!

Do you have any ideas how I could reproduce a 3D plot like the one above?

Comment: Try this to understand the  `outer` function. `outer(1:10,1:10,FUN="+")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(graphics)
dta = cbind(c(2000, 2005, 2015), 
        c(15, 20, 25), 
        c(20, 24, 35))

colnames(dta) <- c('year', 'age', 'rate')
dta = as.data.frame(dta)
persp(dta$year, dta$age, matrix(runif(9),3,3), theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5, col = "lightblue",
      ltheta = 120, shade = 0.75, ticktype = "detailed",
      xlab = "year", ylab = "age", zlab = "rate")
```

Ref: `demo(persp)` in R

Note: The thirs argument (z) must be a matrix

Comment: I got an error from your example **Error in persp.default(dta$year, dta$age, dta$rate, theta = 30, phi = 30,  : 
  invalid 'z' argument**

Comment: Check if `class(dta$rate)` is a factor.

Comment: **Error in if (any(diff(x) <= 0) || any(diff(y) <= 0)) stop("increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(diff(x), 0) : '<=' not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(diff(y), 0) : '<=' not meaningful for factors**

Comment: could you post the plot you get ?

Comment: You are right `z` must be a matrix. Each element in the matrix shows the hight of the points in the surface. You need more values to create a surface.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the plot3d function from "rgl" package. Since you just have a few point, I adjusted the limits so that you can see them.

`library("rgl")
plot3d(dta, xlim=c(1990, 2030), ylim=c(10,30), zlim=c(15,40))`